# "Failed to start project" error by SSIS project in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have VS2012 solution with several different projects, and at last I added one SSIS project to this solution.

Project is simple, consist one packagethat contains Execute SQL Task, and when I build complete project, build succeeded, but when I debug package, then I got error:

```
Failed to start project

Error starting debugging.(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.vsIntegration)
```

Execute SQL Task just execute two lines of code, delete rows and reseed identity, and this works in VS2010 Shell, but in VS2012 not. Connection to database created successfully, because I tested it.

Comment: What happens if you right click on your package in solution explorer and select 'Execute Package'?

Comment: Executing package works perfectly!

Comment: I think the play button turns on hardcore debugging, which you need to make some effort to configure. I will post a more researched answer soon

Comment: Sorry I can't quite work it out but if I do I will return and post the explanation

Comment: I think that you have right when say that play button turns on hardcore debugging, because I was constantly trying to execute package with play button, like in VS2010.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but ran into the same issue this morning. The answer to this question solved it for me. Answering here since this was the first google result for my query. Hopefully it helps someone else down the road!

[IsVisualStudio2012ProInstalled() method not found error when running an SSIS package from VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745396/isvisualstudio2012proinstalled-method-not-found-error-when-running-an-ssis-pac)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error which is how I stumbled on this question. The first thing I tried to do to remedy the problem was to execute the package by right-clicking on the "Package.dtsx" file (as suggested above). I received a message indicating something about the security level being out of sync.  I found that I had "Don'tSaveSensitive" set as the "ProtectionLevel" in the properties on the package, but it was set differently  on the project (the wrench option under the "Project" drop-down menu). Once I got them into sync by making them both "Don'tSaveSensitive" I was able to run it with the "play" button.  I made no other changes to the project/package/files at all.