# IsVisualStudio2012ProInstalled() method not found error when running an SSIS package from VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I'm trying to run an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2012.  When I click the "Start" button I get this very odd error in a popup from Visual Studio:

```
Method not found: 'Boolean 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.VisualStudio2012Utils.IsVisualStudio2012ProInstalled()'. 
(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
```

Clicking on the show technical information, I get this stack trace:

```
===================================

Failed to start project (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.VisualStudio2012Utils.IsVisualStudio2012ProInstalled()'. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32 launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
```

Has anyone ever seen this error before or know what the issue might be?  A bit of googling turned up absolutely nothing for me.

I was able to happily develop and run SSIS packages from Visual Studio 2012 without any issues just a couple days ago (I did reboot my PC over the weekend and some windows updates were installed)

ETA:

I was able to find a couple very recent technet posts about this [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/edfbbb0b-717f-4f4f-b458-fa4b0c1a5006/ssis-package-wont-debug-in-vs2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7aff86e-564e-4a35-adb7-e48aebb7a09c/fail-to-start-project?forum=sqlintegrationservices) so I suspect this was something that broke in an update over the weekend.  One post says he solved the issue by reinstalling, but of course I'd rather not go that route if I don't have to.

Comment: Weird. Any chance your "regular" VS is a trial version and has now expired while the free SSDT shell just keeps chugging along?

Comment: @billinkc - nope, have a licensed version of VS2012 Premium.

Comment: As you said, this started happening after your weekend reboot and updates, can you spot anything in update installed  logs related to the VS or SSIS. If you find then give it a try by uninstalling only those weekend updates.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

1. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS212 as Administrator
2. execute the command `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies"`
3. execute the command `gacutil /if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll`
4. restart Visual Studio

Source msdn [Fail to start project](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7aff86e-564e-4a35-adb7-e48aebb7a09c/fail-to-start-project?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

**For visual Studio 2013** execute the command `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies"` in point 2 and then execute point 3 and 4.

Comment: Brilliant! Easy, to the point, exact instructions, took me 30 secs!

Comment: Using Jeff's answer I created a batch file with this content:"   

    call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"    

    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

    gacutil /if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll    

    pause
"
Which I run in admin mode on my Win7 x64 to fix this recurring issue

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I had to restart VS2012 for this fix to work.

Comment: It doesn't persist if I reboot

Comment: Thanks so much.  Got this error today after upgrading to SP2 for 2012.

Comment: Venkateswarlu Avula's answer is also useful for those, like me, who do not have the VS Developer Command Prompt installed.  It explains where to find gacutil in the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thanks, great reply and I always come back to it when it happens, I'm sure I saved it on my desktop somewhere, but your post is still no 1 ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me at first.  However after I uninstalled and re-installed and still got the error this fix worked.

Answer (score 6):

The following is the command we have to use to resolve the issue:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /if "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll"

Make sure that your dll file and `Gacutil.exe` file locations are correct. It may be different  in other systems.

**Note**: You should open your *“Command Prompt”* as an administrator to run the above command.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem.

Downloaded and installed SQL Server 2012 SP2 and that seemed to have fixed the problem.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you have Visual Studio 2013 and the BI tools for it installed also.  If you use Visual Studio 2013 for the same package it will probably work.  The other answer suggesting the run of gacutil to register the old version may have negative impacts later when you want to use the Visual Studio 2013 tools for SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing just happen and miraculously now my machine has been "fixed".
(I actually had it happen on both a Win 8.1 machine and a new Win 7 machine.)

My colleague and I noticed that the SSIS toolbox was missing from my IDE. After opening an SSIS package, going to the SSIS menu, and adding back in my "SSIS Toolbox", for some strange reason, my packages now run fine.

I'm guessing a recent update reset the behavior of the IDE.?.?

If this black magic worked for me, I'm hoping it will work for others.

**EDIT:**
I had the behavior revert itself.

I uninstalled SQL Server 2012 SP2 HF 5522, then rebooted
I then uninstalled SQL Server 2012 SP2, then rebooted
After that, my IDE still gave the error.
I then tried to apply SQL Server SP1 CU 9, but my environment said it wasn't needed.
I then rebooted one last time.

My SSIS Packages run again.

Voodoo...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running across this issue somewhat after the fact (as I did), it appears that it has been fixed in a later release of the SSDT-BI tools installer.  Either that, or the process of re-installing fixed it for me.

The file name of the installer on the [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) has not changed, but there was a new version released in March of 2015.  The new version number is 11.0.5583.0, and the previous version that was causing this error was 11.0.3436.0.

So a simple update might be sufficient. It worked for me with no changes to the GAC.