# Failure adding assembly to the cache: This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis, etl

I am having this same problem: 
[IsVisualStudio2012ProInstalled() method not found error when running an SSIS package from VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745396/isvisualstudio2012proinstalled-method-not-found-error-when-running-an-ssis-pac) (I didn't have enough rep to comment and ask for help there). This issue started when I had visual studio 2012 installed but then installed visual studio 2015, the shop I work for uses both.

I followed the instructions of the #1 answer but getting the error below

I've entered this in command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe" /if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll
```

Error:

> Failure adding assembly to the cache: This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work by finding a newer version of gacutil that was on my computer. You can see originally I was looking in the v7.0a folder but found another copy in a v8.0a folder that I used that worked.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" 
/if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll
```