# When I'm creating a new project for SSIS i'm getting in Visual Studio Error

Tags: ssis

When I'm creating a new project for SSIS i'm getting in Visual Studio 2019 this

> Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Rroject.
> IsFromOPCStorage()'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IsVisualStudio2012ProInstalled() method not found error when running an SSIS package from VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745396/isvisualstudio2012proinstalled-method-not-found-error-when-running-an-ssis-pac)

Comment: https://arcanecode.com/2015/01/07/sql-server-ssis-ssdt-error-method-not-found-microsoft-sqlserver-dts-design-visualstudio2012utils-isvisualstudio2012proinstalled/